# Displaying errors set on org.​springframework.​validation.Errors object in jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm using a custom Validator for a form input. I use the `org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils` singleton to reject mandatory field entries if they're empty:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", null, "Username is mandatory");
```

Printing those error messages works in my jsp:

```
<form:errors path="username"/>
```

However, I want to do some more 'sophisticated' validation, such as RegEx'ing email input or matching two password entries:

```
errors.reject("verifypw", "Passwords don't match");
```

When the two entered passwords don't match, I want to add an error to the Errors object.
This works as intended and I can check on the controller for errors with

```
public String submitRegisgrationForm(@ModelAttribute("user") PlatformUser user, BindingResult result) {
    userService.validateUserInput(user, result);
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        userService.createNewUser(user);
        return "user/success";
    } else {
        return "user/register";
    }
}
```

Alas, the errors raised through `errors.reject()` can not be accessed like the ones raised through `rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace()`.

```
<form:errors path="verifypw"/>
<label for="verifypw">Verify password: </label>
<form:password path="verifypw" id="verifypw"/>
```

This does not print out any error messages to the jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use;

```
errors.reject("verifypw", "Passwords don't match");
```

You are rejecting the whole form with an error code of `verifypw` and message `Passwords don't match`; you are not rejecting an individual field. Therefore the error won't appear in your JSP with;

```
<form:errors path="verifypw"/>
```

But if you have;

```
<form:errors/>
```

You will see it. To reject an individual field, use;

```
errors.rejectValue("verifypw", "Passwords don't match");
```

Comment: Ok. Should be errors.rejectValue("verifypw", null, "Passwords don't match"); If I don't want to use an error code with value 'Passwords don't match'.. thanks.